# cannot install expo cli FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been using react native with Expo on my MacBook Pro (with 16GB of RAM) for over a year.  I was preparing to upgrade to a newer version of Expo and the instructions said to install the latest version of expo-cli first.

I ran this command:

```
sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```

It fails with this message:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
> failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 0x10003ae75 node::Abort()
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: 0x10003b07f node::OnFatalError(char const*,
> char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  3: 0x1001a7ae5
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  4: 0x100572ef2
> v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  5: 0x1005759c5
> v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  6: 0x10057186f
> v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
> v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]  7: 0x10056fa44
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  8: 0x10057c2dc
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  9: 0x10057c35f
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] 10: 0x10054dca5
> v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int,
> v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node] 11: 0x10067fdf8
> v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>,
> v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node] 12: 0x10069f1a3
> v8::internal::String::IndexOf(v8::internal::Isolate*,
> v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>,
> v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
> 13: 0x100824bbf v8::internal::Runtime_StringIndexOfUnchecked(int,
> v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
> 14: 0x2b7222bdbe3d

How can I get past this?

Comment: first, you should not use `sudo` for npm install! follow this guide instead: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally. second, you can try using a different node version (you didn't specify what version you are using in your question, so it's hard to say). third, you can try bumping the node heap size by adding this to your shell profile: `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by upgrading to a newer version of Node.js.  I followed the "option 2" instructions here (ending with "sudo n latest"):  https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version

When I run "npm --version", I now get 8.1.0